# PHP loading all classes on every page

Tags: php

I'm building a website and are getting more and more classes to load. Currently I'm including every class in index.php and I also have a ajax handler where every class is included, so I basically include all my PHP files at ajax calls and on every page on the website.

Is this bad practice?

I've tried searching a bit around an have seen that there is a function called `spl_autoload_register`. By reading a little about it, my understanding is that it tries to include the files defined if a class is not found. But, how is that different from `require_once` or `include_once`.

Lets say I have the class underneath in a file and then use `require_once('myclass.php');`

```
class Myclass {

    function myMethod {
        //some code here
    }

}
```

But, the class is not in use before I initialize it with `$class = new Myclass;` So what is now the difference from running

```
function my_autoloader($class) {

    require_once('classes/' . $class . '.php');

}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

I would still have to initialize it with `$class = new Myclass;` when I want to use it. Are there some performance gains from either of them or is it more a preference thing?

And one more question. Should PHP be minifyed like its done with JS and CSS or is this pointless with PHP?

Comment: Concentrate on one question at a time (and no, minifying PHP is largely pointless).

Comment: The difference is that `require_once`ing the class always loads the file and causes PHP to parse and execute the code in the file. Autoloading just does that if you're actually using the class. If you're not actually using the class, it saves a bunch of parsing work.

Comment: To concentrate on the last question again. Minimizing php the only benefit would be the file size on your server. there would be no gain to client and page load speeds by minimizing the php file

Comment: You might benefit from refactoring to use Composer.

Comment: JS and CSS files are minified because they are transfered from server to each client. PHP files do not leave the server, there is no point in minifying them.

Comment: @deceze Didn't actually know that, I thought composer actually loads everything and just provides a handy way to include the loaded files wherever you want, thought "use" and "namespaces"

Comment: @Borjante Namespaces (`namespace` and `use`) have absolutely nothing to do with actually loading files. Also, usually with composer you're including dozens or hundreds of external libraries; it would be prohibitive if everything would load at once.

Comment: If you require all your source upfront, this could amount to higher memory usage than cherry picking code that is pertinent to the task in hand.  But much depends on your environment.  What you want to avoid is scanning directories for files.  Like working your way through include paths, to find a file.  Being explicit helps here.  Read the spl_autoload_register documentation.  And check PSR-4.

Comment: Do you have any good source on where to read how composer works internally? Looks like time to learn it after using it for a few years

Comment: @Borjante You don't need to know how Composer works *internally*, just how to define and use libraries which work with it. https://getcomposer.org has a very readable introduction.

Comment: I do want to know how it works internally as I was completely mistaken :)

I know how to use composer, been using it from the begining.

And here some help for the OP:
http://blog.evaldojunior.com/php/development/2014/08/22/autoload-php-english.html

This short article explains the principle pretty well.

Comment: @Borjante Maybe I'm using a slightly different definition of "internally". All I know is that the internals are horribly complicated because they have to do complicated things to resolve dependencies etc. On the other hand, what it *does* is definitely more to do with autoloaders than namespaces. Namespaces in PHP really are just part of the name, they have no existence as a "package" or anything; `use` is just for defining shorthands in a particular file.

Comment: (@Borjante, composer is 'a' package manager, that can help you with auto-loading.  But you don't have to use it.  If you are interested in some of the resultant auto-loading mechanics, check one of composer's generated vendor/composer folder which is readable.)

Comment: Yeah, just looking at it. And don't get me wrong. I've been using composer for the last 4 years lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will technically run faster if you don't load every file on every page, but this will largely go away if you configure "OpCache", which loads all the *compiled* class definitions into shared memory. And at some point, you may end up with a page that needs 90% of your code loaded to do its job anyway. (This is also relevant to your question about minification - PHP is compiled on the server, so minification doesn't really help anyone.)

The other advantage with autoloading though is *maintenance* - when you define a new class, you don't have to add it to some master-list of includes, make sure it loads after its parent class but before its child classes, etc. Instead, you place the class definition in a meaningfully named file and directory (great for humans finding it too!) and the autoloader will find it when it's needed.

Answer (score 2):

**In 2018 the best way to work with autoloading is Composer** - build for easy work and performance optimization.

#### 4. Steps to Load Your Classes Fast and Clean

1. [Download composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx) (for start even right to your project, it's up to you)
2. Create `composer.json` and tell him directories or files to load classes from:

   ```
   {
       "autoload": {
           "classmap": "/src"
       }
   }
   ```

   Using most open and friendly [`classmap` option](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap).
3. Rebuild cache by CLI command:

   ```
   composer.phar dump
   ```
4. Include it in `index.php`

   ```
   require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
   ```

And you're ready to go!

Comment: While true, it doesn’t really answer the question at all.

Comment: 5 years ago I'd agree with you

Answer (score 0):

I did extensive measurements on TYPO3 (PHP) including hundreds of class files on a machine with SSD. I created a script including all available classes. Class reading was not a very expensive part compared to other issues.

I would focus on this optimisation, once all more important questions are addressed.

Comment: Without knowing the environment/experiment/version etc, this doesn't count for much.  Concatenating all your scripts into one file is 'an' optimization technique. As file io can be 'a' bottleneck.

Comment: Compared to OpCache concatenating all scripts sounds like a pour mans optimization technique, but for sure it is one. Both are types of caching and you may encounter the typical issues of caching. 

When file IO becomes your bottleneck you did a good job to work all more narrow bottlenecks away like unnecessary multiple DB requests.